# Kibana pie chart from different fields

Tags: charts, kibana, kibana-4

I have data from a log, as follow:

```
{
  "_index": "XXXXX",
  "_type": "XXXXX",
  "_id": "XXXXX",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    ......
    "@timestamp": "2016-07-14T08:57:07.971Z",
    "ServerId": "4dc8-b7fa-8bcf319",
    "PacketsTotal": 173,
    "PacketsSuccess": 173,
    "PacketsFailed": 0,
    "FramesTotal": 4148,
    "FramesSuccess": 4145,
    "FramesFailed": 3,
    "DurationSeconds": 56
  },
  "fields": {
    "StartTime": [
      ...
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      ...
    ],
    "EndTime": [
      ...
    ],
    "CreateDate": [
      ...
    ],
    "LastUpdateDate": [
      ...
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Now I would like to create a pie chart that visualises Packets and Frames where the slices of the chart will be PacketsSuccess, PacketsFailed, FramesSuccess, FramesSuccess. Is this doable? and if so, how?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, Kibana doesn't work like that because it expects to create the pie from buckets of a single field.  I have raised this issue, however: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/8143